# What should be the Jenkins pipeline strategy for deploying multiple cloudformation stacks in a repository via Jenkins?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation

I have a Git repository with multiple folders. Each folder has multiple cloudformation stacks. I want to perform a CI/CD on entire repository such that only those stacks should be built which have a commit done on them. What should be my pipeline and branching strategy? Can I have have a single pipeline job for each stack? How to have only a particular stack built on a commit done on a branch which contains multiple stacks?

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of different ways to do this; and the unfortunate answer is "do what works for you"; particularly with regard to your pipeline and branching strategy.

You can either create a single pipeline for each stack, or one pipeline to deploy everything. If you go with the one pipeline to deploy everything, an important part of CloudFormation is that, if a template hasn't changed, CloudFormation won't do anything. Therefore, if a commit only updates one stack out of X that you are deploying, only that one stack should update in AWS as there will be some comparison between the templates you're submitting for the update and how they exist in AWS and decide whether or not to update based on any differences.

Comment: Suppose in a branch there are multiple stacks, each stack has its own Jenkins job. When a commit is triggered on a stack I only want that particular stack to be built and not all other cf templates. How can this be accomplished?